# Making Objects Stop at the Edge of the Screen While In Fullscreen Mode

Tags: c#, xna

Recently, I upgraded my game to a fullscreen setting, by adding `graphics.IsFullScreen = true;`, but this seems to have gotten me some errors where the boundaries for movement go.

This is what I have so far, where `bounds` is a rectangle, and `location` a Vector2:

```
if (bounds.Top > GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height - 10)
{
    location.Y = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height - 10;
}

if (bounds.Bottom < GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height - GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height + 10)
{
    location.Y = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height - GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height + 10 + bounds.Height;
}

if (bounds.Left < GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width - 10)
{
    location.X = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width - 10;
}

if (bounds.Right > GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width - GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width + 10)
{
    location.X = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width - GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width + 10 + bounds.Width;
}
```

For some reason, this does not seem to work, and my object seems to disappear from the screen altogether. Oh, and the -10px/+10px is just a 1o pixel border I want around the whole screen! Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode to get the width and height. Even though your monitor and Pc may be running 1920x1080, when you fullscreen an XNA game window, it will rescale the monitor to whatever resolution the game is running at. Such as 1280x800 or whatever.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard what should I use then?

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.

Comment: That depends on what your standard resolution is. If you haven't changed it, I think it's either 800x600, or 1024x768.